# How to determine weather a year is a leap year, and the years thereafter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a *for loop* program that asks the user to input a year and a number of years, to determine firstly if the year entered is a **leap year**, the secondly enter the **number of years thereafter** to check if those are **leap years** as well.

My output should look like this:

**What year do you want to start with?** 1994
**How many years do you want to check?** 8
1994 isn’t a leap year
1995 isn’t a leap year
1996 is a leap year
1997 isn’t a leap year
1998 isn’t a leap year
1999 isn’t a leap year
2000 is a leap year
2001 isn’t a leap year

The code I have thus far works to check the specific year, but I am struggling to *loop* it so that it continues for the years thereafter.

Here is my code:

```
print ("""Enter a year to see if it is a leap year,
then enter the number of years there after you want to check""")

year_start = int(input("\nWhat year do you want to start with?\n"))
num_of_years = int(input("How many years do you want to check?\n"))

# I can't figure out the 'for loop' syntax to loop this statement
if (year_start % 4) == 0:  
   if (year_start % 100) == 0:  
       if (year_start % 400) == 0:  
           print (f"{year_start} is a leap year")  
       else:  
           print (f"{year_start} isn't a leap year")  
   else:  
       print (f"{year_start} is a leap year")  
else:  
   print (f"{year_start} isn't a leap year")
```

Comment: Hi Spike! Welcome to SO! Have you tried `for year in range(year_start, year_start+8):` where your comment is? Indent the rest of the code and replace `year_start` by `year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
print ("""Enter a year to see if it is a leap year,
then enter the number of years there after you want to check""")

year_start = int(input("\nWhat year do you want to start with?\n"))
num_of_years = int(input("How many years do you want to check?\n"))

# I can't figure out the 'for loop' syntax to loop this statement
for i in range(year_start, year_start + num_of_years):
    if (i % 4) == 0:  
        print (f"{i} is a leap year")  
    else:  
       print (f"{i} isn't a leap year")
```

Example output:

```
Enter a year to see if it is a leap year,
then enter the number of years there after you want to check

What year do you want to start with?
1994
How many years do you want to check?
8
1994 isn't a leap year
1995 isn't a leap year
1996 is a leap year
1997 isn't a leap year
1998 isn't a leap year
1999 isn't a leap year
2000 is a leap year
2001 isn't a leap year
```

You can use a `for` loop and use `range` for the sequence to iterate. Then you only need `(i % 4) == 0`, and you don't need the other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Only division by 4 is not enough for finding leap year. You have to check 100 and 400.

Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#/media/File:Leap_Centuries.jpg for leap year.

```
def is_leap_year(year: int) -> bool:
    # Returns True if the given year is a leap year
    return bool((not year % 400) or ((not year % 4) and year % 100))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use range(num_of_years) as follows:

```
for i in range(num_of_years):
```

you should encapsulate all the leap year logic inside that for loop and make some adjustments but you should be able to figure that on your own, good luck.